# PHP How to trim whitespaces a from string

Tags: php, whitespace, removing-whitespace

**I want to know how to replace whitespaces from a String.**

**Example String:** `INFO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [06:57:18 INFO]: 03.06 07:05:32 Auto-saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE: Enabled level saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE`

**I want to make it:** `INFO [06:57:18 INFO]: 03.06 07:05:32 Auto-saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE: Enabled level saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE`

**I tried the following methods which didn't work for me:**

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $foo);
trim($foo);
```

I tried to print it as json to see what is really going on and got this output:
http://pastebin.com/QY8uGt4V *(the output is pretty big)*

Comment: Are you its whitespace? It should be line break, tab

Comment: `preg_replace('/\b+/', '', $foo);`

Comment: @JohnConde I think it's going to be easier: __$foo =__ `preg_replace('/\b+/', '', $foo);`

Comment: Getting this error: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2 in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/[\b]+/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = 'INFO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [06:57:18 INFO]: 03.06 07:05:32 Auto-saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE: Enabled level saving 03.06 07:05:32 [Console] INFO CONSOLE;';
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $str);
echo $output;
```

Comment: No didn't work. I also tried `preg_replace('!\s+!', '', $str);` which removed all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is replace multiple spaces with one? if So you just need to set a space character as the replacement, like this:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $foo);
trim($foo);
```